# Custom timer assert

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assertions

I would like to make a custom Assertion for my unit test, which would measure the execution time of two c# functions and compare them. I have written the code below, but there is a better way?

```
public static class AssertExtensions
{
    public static void MoreSlowThan(Action slowFunction, Action fastFunction)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        slowFunction();
        watch.Stop();
        var watchBis = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        fastFunction();
        watchBis.Stop();
        Assert.IsTrue(watch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= watchBis.ElapsedMilliseconds);
    }
}
```

called in this manner:

```
AssertExtensions.MoreSlowThan(() => MyFunction(), () => MyCachedFunction());
```

The goal is to compare the execution time of a function with the execution time of the same function in cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assert extension is not a real extension yet. But with the new MSTest-2 we got the new `That` property on the `Assert` class that we can use to write *real* extensions for.

You just need to add `this Assert assert` to your method to make it work that way.

This is not the only improvement you should make. Assert methods parameters usually follow the pattern *exptected* + *actual* - in that order. You should name your parameters accordingly so there is no doubt about what they are for.

The last thing you should change is the condition inside `Assert.True`. Instead of comparing just milliseconds it's easier to use the `Elapsed` property.

```
public static void IsSlower(this Assert assert, Action expectedFastAction, Action actualSlowAction)
{
    var slowStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    actualSlowAction();
    slowStopwatch.Stop();

    var fastStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    expectedFastAction();
    fastStopwatch.Stop();

    Assert.IsTrue(slowStopwatch.Elapsed >= fastStopwatch.Elapsed);
}
```

Now you can use it like this (with parameter order changed to address the issue expected+actual):

```
Assert.That.IsSlower(() => MyCachedFunction(), () => MyFunction());
```

It would also be a good idea to add a message to `IsTrue` saying something that the second action wasn't actually slower it it fails. Otherwise you'll just see a generic information.

```
Assert.IsTrue(
    slowStopwatch.Elapsed >= fastStopwatch.Elapsed, 
    $"Slower action wasn't actually slower. Faster elapsed:  {fastStopwatch.Elapsed} Slower elapsed: {slowStopwatch.Elapsed}");
```